# Line height spacing for text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-breaks

I am trying to reduce the space between my long axis labels. In base R graphics I would use `lheight`, but is seems to have no effect in ggplot. Is there a ggplot equivalent?

Toy example to show the problem:

```
library("tidyverse")
df0 <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  mutate(car = str_wrap(car, width = 10))

ggplot(data = df0, aes(x = car, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()

# has no effect
par(lheight = 0.5)
ggplot(data = df0, aes(x = car, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: See `ggsave`, `png`/`jpg` and/or specify the size of the text with  `theme(axis.text = element_text(size=..)`

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus As I understand it that will decease the size of the text (and the space between the lines) rather than than just the size of the space between the lines? ...which is what I am after.

Comment: If we are after "avoid overlap", we could left align multiple line names, and right align single line names?

Comment: Similar to this one: [padwrap <- function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34750931/680068)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may be looking for a combination of options. The closest to `lheight` is likely setting `lineheight` in `element_text`. I also made the font smaller, just to show options.

```
ggplot(data = df0, aes(x = car, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(lineheight = 0.5, 
                                   size = 6))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and I found a solution in reducing my list with: slice(1:40)

```
library("tidyverse")
df0 <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  mutate(car = str_wrap(car, width = 10)) %>% slice(1:40)

ggplot(data = df0, aes(x = car, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()

# has no effect
par(lheight = 0.6)
ggplot(data = df0, aes(x = car, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()

ggplot(data = df0, aes(x = car, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(lineheight = 0.6, size = 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `guide_axis` with `n.dodge` in `scale_y_discrete` to automatically dodge the labels like this:

```r
library("tidyverse")
df0 <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  mutate(car = str_wrap(car, width = 10))

ggplot(data = df0, aes(x = car, y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>