# How do I left justify when using line breaks using ggrepel?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

How do I left justify my label using `geom_text_repel`? In the example below, I would like the word "very" to be underneath the word "this". Here I use the left justify setting i.e., `hjust = 0`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, drat, label = "this label is so long \n very long \n very long")) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(data = mtcars %>% 
                    filter(hp == max(hp)),
                  nudge_x = 0.4,
                  segment.color = 'transparent',
                  size = 3,
                  force =0.2,
                  hjust = 0)
```

[image]

I may need to approach this problem using `annotate` instead of `ggrepel`
see - [Justifying lines of text within individual ggrepel labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448262/justifying-lines-of-text-within-individual-ggrepel-labels) , but `ggrepel` would be preferable

Another option may be to use `grid::grid.gedit`, but I don't understand how to apply this framework to `ggrepel` see - [ggplot2: How to left-justify text from multi-line facet labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749636/ggplot2-how-to-left-justify-text-from-multi-line-facet-labels)

Edit: The problem in this question is similar to [Override horizontal positioning with ggrepel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028991/override-horizontal-positioning-with-ggrepel) , but the questions differ in that here I use `hjust = 0`, whereas the other question uses `hjust = "outward"`

Comment: I have to say it would be _expected behavior_ for `hjust = 0` to left-justify multiline labels / text, and `hjust = 1` to right-justify them. I can't think of a possible reason someone would want to left-justify their text (as shown in the `ggrepel` vignette) but have subsequent lines centered! If no one else has an easy solution, I would open an issue in the `ggrepel` github project.

Comment: See related problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028991/override-horizontal-positioning-with-ggrepel/